# Dynamic chaining of properties in sketch

Tags: color, sketch-app, interface-design

Is there a way to chain 2 or more properties of different layers in sketch. To give an example : Chain a fill of a button to the fill of a text layer on it, so that, in case the button H/S/B changes, the text H/S/B changes accordingly. The question is pre-dominantly from a theming point of view.

I have tried the sketch plugin "Chain" and even though its awesome, its not serving my need fully.